# Password Style TextCellEditor showing original characters in TableViewer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface, eclipse-plugin

`TextCellEditor` **passEdit** has **SWT.PASSWORD** style. But when **Add** button was clicked original characters were shown instead of default ***** echo characters. Also focus listeners on **passEdit** were not working. i.e When user double clicks it should show original characters and on focus lost it should show password echo characters.

How to fix this?

```java
    public class UserAddSolution {

    public static boolean flag = true;
    private TextCellEditor userNameEdit;
    private TextCellEditor passEdit;

    class UserNamePassword {
        private final String name;
        private final String password;

        public UserNamePassword(String name, String password) {
            this.name = name;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }
    }

    public UserAddSolution(final Shell shell) {
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
        GridData layoutData = new GridData();
        layoutData.heightHint = 300;
        shell.setLayoutData(layoutData);

        final TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.BORDER
                | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.MULTI);
        viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
        Table table = viewer.getTable();
        table.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        table.setLayoutData(layoutData);
        userNameEdit = new TextCellEditor(table);
        passEdit = new TextCellEditor(table, SWT.PASSWORD);
        final Text tex = (Text) passEdit.getControl();
        final char echar = tex.getEchoChar();
        tex.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                tex.setEchoChar(echar);

            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                tex.setEchoChar('\0');
            }
        });
        viewer.setCellEditors(new CellEditor[] { userNameEdit, passEdit });
        viewer.setCellModifier(new ICellModifier() {

            @Override
            public boolean canModify(Object element, String property) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object element, String property) {
                UserNamePassword ele = (UserNamePassword) element;
                if (property.equals("1")) {
                    return ele.getName();
                } else if (property.equals("2")) {
                    return ele.getPassword();
                }
                return "";

            }

            @Override
            public void modify(Object element, String property, Object value) {
            }

        });

        viewer.setColumnProperties(new String[] { "1", "2" });
        ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy actSupport = new ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy(
                viewer) {
            @Override
            protected boolean isEditorActivationEvent(
                    ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent event) {
                return event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.TRAVERSAL
                        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.MOUSE_DOUBLE_CLICK_SELECTION
                        || event.eventType == ColumnViewerEditorActivationEvent.PROGRAMMATIC;
            }
        };

        int feature = ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_HORIZONTAL
                | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_MOVE_TO_ROW_NEIGHBOR
                | ColumnViewerEditor.TABBING_VERTICAL
                | ColumnViewerEditor.KEYBOARD_ACTIVATION;

        TableViewerEditor.create(viewer, actSupport, feature);

        TableViewerColumn userNameColumn;
        userNameColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        userNameColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);
        userNameColumn.getColumn().setMoveable(true);
        userNameColumn.getColumn().setText("Name");
        userNameColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                return super.getImage(element);
            }

            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                UserNamePassword fdf = (UserNamePassword) element;
                return super.getText(fdf.getName());
            }
        });
        TableViewerColumn passwordColumn;
        passwordColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        passwordColumn.getColumn().setWidth(200);
        passwordColumn.getColumn().setMoveable(true);
        passwordColumn.getColumn().setText("Password");
        passwordColumn.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {

            @Override
            public Image getImage(Object element) {
                return super.getImage(element);
            }

            @Override
            public String getText(Object element) {
                UserNamePassword fdf = (UserNamePassword) element;
                return super.getText(fdf.getPassword());
            }

            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                super.update(cell);
            }
        });

        viewer.setInput(new ArrayList<UserNamePassword>());
        table.setLinesVisible(true);
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);

        viewer.refresh();
        Button add = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        add.setText("Add");
        add.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                viewer.add(new UserNamePassword("abc", "xyz"));
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        new UserAddSolution(shell);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ColumnLabelProvider` is responsible for displaying the data in the table. The text widget appears only when you edit a cell. That's why you need to tell the label provider to mask characters and not to display the plain text.

As a consequence you don't need to set `SWT.PASSWORD` style to the `passEdit` since you want to display the password in the editor as plain text:

```java
passEdit = new TextCellEditor(table, SWT.NONE);
```

You also don't need the `FocusListener` and you can set the echo char as a constant:

```java
private static final String ECHARSTR = Character.toString((char)9679);
```

So you can remove 15 lines below the initialization of `passEdit`

I don't know if there is a solution for this in JFace (I think not) but you can easily solve this by modifying your existing label provider. My suggestion is to modify the `getText()` method of `ColumnLabelProvider` for `passwordColumn` as follows:

```java
@Override
public String getText(Object element)
{
    UserNamePassword fdf = (UserNamePassword)element;
    return fdf.getPassword().replaceAll(".", ECHARSTR);
}
```